# How to set NA = to two different values?

Tags: r, new-operator, na

How can I set my NA to two different things?

My data set uses 0 and nd to represent missing data and I got my code to work for one value, but I cannot get it for both.

I tried to separate NA = and a comma, but I cannot get it to work.

Also, this is the way I have to do this, and I am a beginner programmer so please keep it simple

```
seals <- read_csv("SealData.csv", na =  "nd", "0")
```

Comment: Try `seals <- read_csv("SealData.csv", na =  c("nd", "0"))`. That is, you appear to have just forgotten to wrap your NA values in `c()`

Comment: Should work by concatenating both values as `na = c("nd","0")`

Comment: the argument na should be a vector, like this `seals <- read_csv("SealData.csv", na =  c("nd", "0"))`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify multiple NA values, you need to use `c()`.

```
 seals <- read_csv("SealData.csv", na.strings =  c("nd", "0"))
```

Comment: *Whenever you want to specify multiple values, you need to use "c()".* ...This is **not right.**

Comment: Oops! Typo when I copied and pasted code from user's question. Thanks, M.

Comment: Yes, that was an issue you figured on your own. I was talking about the word *Whenever*. Sometimes, you need to use `list()`, etc. I changed the text above your code to be exclusive to this question. Cheers.

Comment: @M-- True! Thanks